C# Access to Sqlite database after moving the file
This is a .NET (MAUI) application. As part of the update routine, I download and replace Sqlite .db3 file.
Initially, I started with:
File.Move(oldFile, newFile);
var result = RunQuery();

I noticed that when the query was being executed before the move operation was fully completed (resulting in i/o error). I decided to write my async copy function:
await using (var sourceStream = File.Open(sourceFile, FileMode.Open))
  {
    var options = new FileStreamOptions()
      {
         Mode = FileMode.Create,
         Access = FileAccess.Write,
         BufferSize = 0
      };
    await using (var destinationStream = File.Open(destinationFile, options))
      {
         await sourceStream.CopyToAsync(destinationStream);
         sourceStream.Close();
         destinationStream.Close();
         File.Delete(sourceFile);
      }
  }

This has somewhat improved the situation, but on every few runs, I get either malformed database or, worse, table X not found errors.
I never had issues if I added a manual delay between the move and the query. But this is not a reliable solution.
What would be a good way to confirm that the file is written completely and ready for queries?

you may need to use some lower level file operations that allow you to know when the write is complete and flushed

See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162983/system-io-file-move-how-to-wait-for-move-completion

You can try to use the Task.Wait()  to wait the file moving completed.

@LiyunZhang-MSFT Can you clarify what to wait for? All of the calls are awaited, but I might be missing something.

Wait for the IO operation completed and then doing the query.

That's what I do @LiyunZhang-MSFT, as you can see above, copy is async and I wait for it. Then I close the stream. The file is written, I can open the database, but it either says the table does not exist, or malformed file. How can I confirm the IO operation is actually completed ?

You can refet to this case: How to wait for async method to complete?.

Perhaps things have changed recently, but in .NET moving files does not wait for the IO operation to complete so you'll need to do a bit of trickery to make it work. In the past I've used a static method / helper, something like this should do the trick.
code:
public static class FileMoveHelper
{
    public async Task MoveFileAsync(string sourceFullFilePath, string destinationFullFilePath, int timeoutSeconds = 60)
    {
        // this will be a non-io blocking call
        File.Move(sourceFullFilePath, destinationFullFilePath);

        // Define a task to monitor if the file exists at the destination path
        var fileMovedTask = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while (!File.Exists(destinationFullFilePath))
            {
                await Task.Delay(50); // Small delay to prevent CPU-bound loops
            }
            return true;
        });

        // Define a timeout task
        var delayTask = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutSeconds));

        // Wait for either the file move completion or timeout
        if (await Task.WhenAny(fileMovedTask, delayTask) == delayTask)
        {
            // Handle timeout scenario
            throw new TimeoutException($"File move operation timed out after {timeoutSeconds} seconds.");
        }

        // Ensure the file move actually completed successfully
        if (!await fileMovedTask)
        {
            throw new IOException("File move operation did not complete successfully.");
        }
    }
}

You'd probably want to extend this slightly with a cancellation token, and more guard clauses to ensure the source file exists and your app can write to the destination folder.
usage:
await MoveFileAsync(oldFile, newFile, 30)

Hope this helps.
PS. I appreciate static methods / classes are problematic for unit testing so feel free to rewrite this into a concrete class and inject it using your preferred DI library.

Thanks for your answer @Kane, I am not sure how this would help. The file exists anyways, I can even open it, but SQLite complains that it is either malformed or the table does not exists.
